# Offline Sentiment Analysis Lib with java

Tags: java, sentiment-analysis

I have an offline tweets corpus. I am trying to do sentiment analysis on it offline classifying each tweet to 'Positive', 'Negative', 'Neutral'.

Is there a java lib that I can use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the sentiment analysis implementation by the Stanford NLP group (http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/). You can find some source code here: https://blog.openshift.com/day-20-stanford-corenlp-performing-sentiment-analysis-of-twitter-using-java/

Another alternative is to use a word-emotion association lexicon as found here: http://saifmohammad.com/WebPages/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon.htm.
A simple approach is tidying the tweet and counting the negative and positive words as found in the lexicon.